# No outlining or intellisense when connecting to Azure though SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms

Is there a way to turn the outlining on when I connect to azure in SSMS?

I have an on-prem sql server connection that shows outlining (screenshot 1). When I connect to my azure server, I don't see outlining (screenshot 2).

I had already tried to google for the solution and it led me to go to Edit> Outlining> start automatic outlining. I see these steps when I'm connecting to the on-prem sql server but not when connecting to Azure.

Additionally, something else I noticed is that intellisense is not working when I'm connected to azure but works fine for the on-prem server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "outlining"? I don't see any obvious differences in the above images.

Comment: Outlining allows you to collapse queries (the little plus/minus signs).  And it works for me connected to Azure.

Comment: With SQL Profiler running, open SSMS. You will see SSMS execute a lot of queries on SQL Server (mostly to figure out server version and features enabled) under Application Name "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio". Once you open a query window you will see a lot of queries being run under "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Transact-SQL IntelliSense" Application Name. Check if your Azure DB admin is blocking queries under these application names.

Comment: Yes sorry should had explained it better but Andrew is correct; refer to the little plus/minus signs. Thanks @Alex! I'll talk to IT to see if this permission is blocked. I noticed those signs are there when I connect to a on-prem MySQL database but for some reason it doesn't show when connected to Azure.